# Password input field in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have completed my application now in `IE` and everything was working fine, then I ran my application in Safari and Chrome and come across an issue where when I have a `Input field` of type `Password` the icon to display the password and the message box to inform the user Caps lock is on isn't there.

Now I know different browsers support different things and I was just wondering has anyone found anything that I can use or add to my code to get this to work?

Here is what I mean (IE):

[image]

This is now is Safari:

[image]

```
<%-- Password Input --%>
<input runat="server" id="txt_password" class="InputBoxLoginPage" type="password" placeholder="Password..." />
```

Comment: post your script and make jsfiddle

Comment: We need the javascript/CSS/html that gives you this result.

Comment: I think thats's a default option in newer IE (10+)(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj128374(v=vs.85).aspx)  - A little old but - http://www.sitepoint.com/better-passwords-3-caps-lock-warnings/

Comment: @PawanLakhara I don't have Script, I just had an Input box with type password. I will edit the question with the HTML I used.

Comment: @misterManSam I just used a Type="Password" I have added the HTML but didnt use JS or CSS.

Comment: There must be HTML/CSS that shows the "Caps Lock is on" message! Can you add whatever code is checking for caps lock?

Comment: @misterManSam No there is no need to write css for this. IE automatically does this for Password field.

Comment: @user3129331 Check my work around and let me know what do you think of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what you mean. I too had this issue. Different browser render the password field differently. So I used this workaround:

```
<div class="well_head" style="height: 36px;">  
    <input type="text" class="password" style="border: 0px; float: right; padding-left: 30px;" />  
    <input type="password" class="password" style="border: 0px; float: right; padding-left: 30px;" />  
    <i class="icon-password" style="float: left; margin-top: 4px;"></i>  
</div>
<div id="capsWarning" style="display:none;">Caps Lock is on.</div>
```

And here is the code by @misterManSam for caps lock popup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    /*   
    * Bind to capslockstate events and update display based on state   
    */  
    $(window).bind("capsOn", function(event) {  
        if ($("#Passwd:focus").length > 0) {  
            $("#capsWarning").show();  
        }  
    });  
    $(window).bind("capsOff capsUnknown", function(event) {  
        $("#capsWarning").hide();  
    });  
    $("#Passwd").bind("focusout", function(event) {  
        $("#capsWarning").hide();  
    });  
    $("#Passwd").bind("focusin", function(event) {  
        if ($(window).capslockstate("state") === true) {  
            $("#capsWarning").show();  
        }  
    });  

    /*   
    * Initialize the capslockstate plugin.  
    * Monitoring is happening at the window level.  
    */  
    $(window).capslockstate();  

});
```

I am using AngularJS and on click of that icon I am toggling the two field.
Also both fields (text and password) are bound to same variable.

This worked for me. Hope it will help you too.

PS. Do your style for that CapsLock Popup div :)
All the best.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so that caps lock warning is IE based. Didn't know that :)

A good solution would be to emulate this with jQuery and HTML/CSS.

[This is a fiddle I found](http://jsfiddle.net/nosilleg/tBB58/). Start typing in the password field with caps lock on to receive the warning.

[This is the github page for the jQuery plugin.](https://github.com/nosilleg/capslockstate-jquery-plugin)

Here is its simple implementation.

HTML

```
<div id="form">
  username
  <input type="text" />
  <br>
  password
  <input type="password" name="Passwd" id="Passwd" />
  <div id="capsWarning" style="display:none;">Caps Lock is on.</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* 
    * Bind to capslockstate events and update display based on state 
    */
    $(window).bind("capsOn", function(event) {
        if ($("#Passwd:focus").length > 0) {
            $("#capsWarning").show();
        }
    });
    $(window).bind("capsOff capsUnknown", function(event) {
        $("#capsWarning").hide();
    });
    $("#Passwd").bind("focusout", function(event) {
        $("#capsWarning").hide();
    });
    $("#Passwd").bind("focusin", function(event) {
        if ($(window).capslockstate("state") === true) {
            $("#capsWarning").show();
        }
    });

    /* 
    * Initialize the capslockstate plugin.
    * Monitoring is happening at the window level.
    */
    $(window).capslockstate();

});
```

For the CSS, you can target `#capsWarning` and make it look however you want.

Comment: Nice. Also want to remind you.. "the icon to display the password isn't there." So adding your code to my one can complete this answer. :) Thanks.